# keep annotation and legend within same seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to generate some figures.

```
import seaborn as sns
g=sns.JointGrid(...)
```

At the end, I need to add a legend and annotate the plot. I do:

```
...
g.ax_joint.legend(...)
...
g.annotate(scipy.stats.spearmanr,fontsize=14)
```

but after the `annotate()` the legend is not there anymore. How to keep both on the same ax_joint in the same figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g.annotate` adds the annotation information as a legend. Adding a new legend in a plot which already has a legend will replace the old legend. The solution is to readd the old legend to the plot.

```
oldlegend = plt.legend(<something>)
newlegend = plt.legend(<something else>)
plt.gca().add_artist(legend)
```

For this case it would look like

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

mydataset=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,2),columns=['a','b'])
g = sns.JointGrid(x=mydataset['a'], y=mydataset['b'])
g=g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot,color='black',
                   kde=True,hist=False,rug=True,bins=20)
g=g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,label='X')        


legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':8}
legendMain=g.ax_joint.legend(prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')


legendSide=g.ax_marg_x.legend(labels=["x"], 
                              prop=legend_properties,loc='upper right')
g.annotate(scipy.stats.spearmanr,fontsize=14, loc=4)
g.ax_joint.add_artist(legendMain)
plt.show()
```

[image]